# Dynamics CRM entity Security roles

Tags: dynamics-crm

Which Dynamics CRM entity should be assigned to a Security role, so that the user has access to the Security roles module and in turn they can create security roles?

Comment: you will need to have system customizer or system admin rights. Configuring/creating security role is kind of System Admin job and Dynamics inherently made it in a way so that mentioned roles could access it.

Comment: any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign System Customizer role in Dynamics CRM to the user.

Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful

Comment: The problem is that a role has already been created with all the functions that the user needs, but the only thing that does not appear is the access icon to Security Roles, I do not know which entity is the one that enables this icon

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided read access to SettingsSiteMap under CustomEntities?
If not request you add that, it might help.

Also provide Create, Read and Write access to Security Role entity under Business Management if not done already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new custom security role that only has access to "Security Role" entity and give to whoever needed it.

[Create an administrative user and prevent elevation of security role privilege](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/prevent-elevation-security-role-privilege)

[image]